# How to Re-Direct from Jquery modal pop up to the different page in a parent's frame

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a problem where I have one page containing a login link. When selected I'm opening a Jquery modal pop up(color box) containing a login page.

In login page a login control is placed and on successful login it should redirect to Home page. But currently when i successfully login to the application the new page is opening in the modal pop up itself.

Is there any solution to open the page in the same window of the parent of modal pop up?

Comment: Post your code that you are currently using.

Answer (score 0):

You must address the top window as:

```
$(location, window.top.document).attr('href', url);
```

url is the address you won to redirect.